# Using map reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, chart.js

I'm trying to use mapreduce to calculate monthly sales and graph with chart.js later.

Suppose I have a JSON response with fields, amount and date.

For my map function, I took out the month:

```
 month = _.map([items[i].transactionDate], function(date) { 
     return {
         lables: items[i].transactionDate.slice(5,7)
     }; 
});
```

and for my reduce function ... well I didn't know what to do here.

```
  sum = _.reduce([items[i].amt], function(memo, num) {
      return memo + items[i].amt
  });
```

I realized that this will eventually calculate total sum not per month. Problem is that I don't know how to relate the two functions properly.

Edit: Per request, my JSON :

```
 "items": [
 {
"_id": "56d1cf3704aee3c68d89cc09",
"amt": 5,
"transactionDate": "2016-02-27T16:30:47.561Z",
 }
]
```

and what I'm trying to get out of this is sales per month on a graph. so far I've been able to project months and total sale but not sales per a specific month.

Comment: can you show you JSON?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about how the data looks like? Maybe a small section of data format. Also what exactly are you looking for in the final output?

Comment: The JSON you have provided and the snippet you provided doesnt seem to gel in your snippet you have `transactionDate` but in json there is nothing like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, simply make one loop with adding new variable

```
let result= {};

_.forEach(items, (item) => {
    // get month
    let month = item.transactionDate.slice(5,7);
    // get amount
    let amount = item.amt;

    // check if we have this month in finaly object
    if(month in finaly) {
       // added amount
       result[month] += amount;
    } else {
       // if this month doesn't exist added with inital value
       result[month ] = amount;
    }
});
```

When you can get all amount of certain month or get sum of all months

```
let allSum = _.reduce(result, (sum, amount) => sum += amount);
let amountInCertainMonth = result["01"];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) are functions of Array that iterate over the array for you

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array with the results of the mapping function for each element

```
var months = items.map ( item => item.transactionDate.slice(5,7) )
```

and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) applies the reducing function to each element and an accumulator.

```
var sum = items.reduce( (accum, item) => accum + item.amt , 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `items[i]` is an object that has `.transactionsDate` and `.amt` as two arrays with corresponding indices. If so, you can get sales per month and total sales within one `reduce` function by starting with `{ totalSales, months }`.

```
var chartData = items[i].transactionDate.reduce(function(total, month, index) {
    var monthlyData = {
        label: month.slice(5, 7),
        sales: items[i].amt[index]
    };
    total.months.push(monthlyData);
    total.totalSales += item.amt;
    return total;
}, { 
    totalSales: 0, months: []
});

// get total sales
var totalSales = chartData.totalSales;
// get sales for May starting at index 0
var salesForMay = chartdata.months[4];
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here is how to use reduce as a group by

```js
    var results = items
        .map(function(data){
            return {"month": data.transactionDate.slice(0,7), "amt": data.amt};
        })
        .reduce(function(amounts, data){            
            if (!amounts.hasOwnProperty(data.month))
                amounts[data.month] = data.amt;
            else
                amounts[data.month] = amounts[data.month] + data.amt;

            return amounts;
 
        }, {});
```